# How to resolve circular reference in Json without Newtonsoft Json?

Tags: c#, json

My project doesn't support Newtonsoft Json. My serialization is like this:

```
return Json(new
    {
        StatusCode = 200,
        Clientes = listaClientes, 
        Total = totalPaginas
    }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

And I'm getting circular reference.

There is an equivalent to `Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore` in `Controller.Json`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the attribute `System.Web.Script.Serialization.ScriptIgnoreAttribute` to the property causing the circular reference.

This should do the trick.